# How to completely destory passport/express session?

Tags: express, passport.js, express-session

I've tried

```
req.session.destroy();
req.logout();
req.logOut();
```

After the logout I check

```
req.isAuthenticated()
```

Returns **false**.

But If I go to **/login** again it will **automatically authenticate me** with the same user without taking me to the login form.

Im using the OAuth2Strategy strategy for passport connecting it to ORCID. I would like to completely destroy the session so if I want to login again I can do it with a different user.

This is how I have it setup:

```
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret,
    saveUninitialized: 'true',
    resave: 'true'
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.use(new OAuth2Strategy({
    scope: '/authenticate',
    authorizationURL: '',
    tokenURL: '',
    clientID: '',
    clientSecret: '',
    callbackURL: '',
    passReqToCallback: true
},
    (req, accessToken, refreshToken, params, profile, cb) => {
        cb(null, data);
    }
));
```

I'm building a SPA so I would like the /logout route to only return me the success status and that the next time I try to login to take me to the form instead of authenticating me based on I guess the cookie or something.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was something specific of orcID, I have to [forcelogout](https://members.orcid.org/api/customize-oauth-login-screen#logout)